# Swift 4 iOS - Completely override system font without compromising storyboard font size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, swift4.2

I would like to:

1. override the default font in all the application choosing the font size from the storyboard
2. if possibile see a preview of the custom font in the text visualized in the storyboard.

I managed to insert the custom font but I have problems in the texts sizing.

I tried the following solutions but they still don't completely fit my requirements:

1. Added this row in the `AppDelegate` inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions func:
    `UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "yourFont", size: yourSize)`
   this overrides font for all UILabels but it overrides the font size too.
   All labels comes with the same `yourSize` font size.
2. I extended the UILabel forcing it executing changeFontName.

   ```
   extension UILabel {
       override open func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()
           changeFontName()
       }

       func changeFontName() {
           self.font = UIFont(name: "yourFont", size: self.font.pointSize)
       }
   }
   ```

   This is working but storyboard obviously does not update the view. And I'm not sure that it is the proper way of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I approached it's similar to the `#2 solution` but it renders the font on the storyboard too.

We created some classes that extend the default UIViews, for example for `UILabel` and `UIButton`. You can do something like this:

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomUILabel: UILabel {

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureLabel()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        configureLabel()
    }

    func configureLabel() {
        font = UIFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }

}

@IBDesignable
public class CustomUIButton: UIButton {

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureLabel()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        configureLabel()
    }

    func configureLabel() {
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: self.titleLabel!.font.pointSize)
    }

}
```

Then in the storyboard we set in the `Identity Inspector` that class as `Custom Class` to each component that had to change the font.

It is not the most clean solution, but at least if you change the `MyCustomFont` font in the whole application you can just change it by code in one single shot.